# disable a button after click In as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am pretty new to as3 and tried searching around for an answer to my question but it seems nothing works. I have an xml loaded file where when the user clicks the correct option (of 4) they get a point scored. I'm trying to disable the button after it has been clicked once but this is not happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the section I have.

```
function setupButtons():void {
    for (var obj:Object in buttons)
    {
        buttons[obj].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkAnswer);
    }   
        buttons[obj].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,disableBtns);
}

function disableBtns(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var obj:Object in buttons)
    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,disableBtns);
    buttons[obj].enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some comments next to your original code to help explain what is likely happening:

```
function setupButtons():void {
    //you're adding a click listener for every object in `buttons`
    for (var obj:Object in buttons)
    {
        buttons[obj].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkAnswer);
    }   

    //this next line seems out of place, 
    //it is NOT a part of your for loop above so it will only run once, 
    //The value of obj will be the LAST item in the for loop above

    buttons[obj].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,disableBtns);
}

function disableBtns(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    //you don't have curly braces on this next for loop line
    //this means it's only going to run the line immediately following the loop as part of the loop.
    for (var obj:Object in buttons)
    //your attempting to remove the same listener over and over again (since this line is in a loop)
    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,disableBtns);
    //this next line is not part of the loop above. 
    //I imagine you only want to disable the button that was clicked (evt.currentTarget)
    //This will only disable whatever the last value of obj was in the loop above
    buttons[obj].enabled = false;
}
```

---

Now, here is a simple code refactoring that may help:

```
//first, just have one click listener for each button, forget the mouse up listener
function setupButtons():void {
    for (var obj:Object in buttons){
        buttons[obj].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
    }
}

function btnClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    //If buttons are of the SimpleButton class, you can just disable them
    evt.currentTarget.enabled = false;

    //OR, if the buttons are not of the SimpleButton class
    evt.currentTarget.mouseChildren = false;
    evt.currentTarget.mouseEnabled = false;

    //OR, just remove the click listener
    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);

    //run the checkAnswer function
    checkAnswer(evt);
}
```

---

To disable all buttons when any 1 is clicked, you could do this:

```
function btnClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var obj:Object in buttons){
        buttons[obj].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
    }

    //run the checkAnswer function
    checkAnswer(evt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.That's certainly cleaner and more logical. however, I tried it but it still doesn't disable the button. I am able to click on it multiple times and each time it keeps incrementing the score (checkAnswer function.

Comment: I edited the answer to show a couple other things you could try to disable the button in the `btnClick` function.  Take out the enabled line if trying one of the others.

Comment: Thanks again my friend. I tried both options you gave and they worked.

Comment: +1 I have an additional question. There are 4 buttons on the stage and I want to disable them all when any 1 is clicked. As it is they each get disabled individually.

Comment: Edited the answer, basically just replace `evt.currentTarget` with `buttons[obj]` inside a for loop that's the same as the other for loops.   If you feel this answers your question, please accept the answer for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: Your answers are all good but I can't find anywhere on the site to officially "accept" your answer. (Guess you can tell I'm a novice here also). I'll definitely accept it if I can find out how to.

Comment: @Don just click that **tick** mark. You can also upvote it since it's useful info.

Comment: @Don http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow how to accept an answer